# How to retrieve User or Admin Images??how to clear that CDA cache memory?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to pentaho CDE Design..

If ones user or Admin logged in to the pentaho dashboard.

- If admin has logged in his image should be displayed.
- Or user logged in to that his image should be displayed using Session ID

how to clear that CDA cache memory?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to retrieve the context of the logged user :

Being in a component, you can do :

this.dashboard.context.user to get the userid
this.dashboard.context.roles to get the roles of the user : it is an array which will contain 'Administrator' if the user is an admin

Then, you can load and display the image you want.